# PHP Curl HTTP 500 error

Tags: php, http, curl, libcurl

I want to make an automatized register on that website and always the server send back the 500 error. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.hobba.fm/register');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.hobba.fm/account/register'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '_token=94ZCzU8O0wYQj1KGq6cOPHaKnAk4hcGAfQzg5DKg&registration-gender=M&registration-name=dkuser20&registration-email=dkuser20@hotmail.com&registration-day=10&registration-month=10&registration-year=1990&registration-password=123456&registration-password-v=123456&registration-disclaimer=on');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
$response = curl_exec($ch); 

if (!$response) { 
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch); 
    echo "<pre>";print_R($http_code);
    die(' Unable to connect to server. Please come back later.');        
    curl_close($ch);        
} 
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

And the server response is this one :

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://www.hobba.fm/account/register
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 500
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 525
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 5.453
    [namelookup_time] => 0.015
    [connect_time] => 0.015
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.015
    [size_upload] => 288
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 52
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 5.453
    [redirect_time] => 0
)
 Unable to connect to server. Please come back later.
```

I do have curl enabled on the server because is a localhost, and the package is this one :

Click [The Image Package here](http://stuff.webcindario.com/codes/package.png)

Any ideas why isn't working this code on that server, I read another post and they said it was because of SSL but doesn't work either.

For the record, the token it's always the same, just changes per day.

I would really aprecciate any help on this issue

Comment: Can it be that the token `_token=94ZCzU8O0wYQj1KGq6cOPHaKnAk4hcGAfQzg5DKg` is bound to your IP-address and doesn't work on others, because its generic? Next question: Is it okay for hobba.fm to let a bot register people?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, well I did change mi ip capturing the package and trust me the token doesn't change, just changes per day and my intention it's not making a bot-register, just learn about curl and even if I want to, I couldn't do it because it's not allowed to register more than 10 users for each IP